# how do you change the color of cells in highcharts heatmap?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

has anybody played around with the new highcharts library. This is the sample jsfiddle I am looking at:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/heatmap/
```

Each cell color is blue, it needs to change based on the data in cells. I thought this line of code was supposed to do that. Any ideas how to change the color or each cell based on data. For example if we are working with data from 1 to 10. if the data in a cell is 1, the cell should be green colour if the data is 10 is should be read, based on the following options. Any ideas how to do this?

```
colorAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0,'green'],
                [0.5,'orange'],
                [0.9,'red']
            ],
            min: -20
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        stops: [

        [0, '#FF0000'],
       [1, '#00FF00'],
       [2, '#FFA500'],
       [3,'#FFFF00']

    ],
        min: 0,
        max: 1
```

This will give you the exact colours also in the series you need to give the json Object like this:
{"x":0,"y":0,"value":0,"myData":"Critical"}  The value is the attribute which gives exact colour

Answer (score 1):

Use `colors` for list of colors,

In `colorAxis`  declare `dataClassColor as 'category'` and define your data range in 
`dataClasses`

```
colors : ['#D7EDE5', '#9BD1BE', '#37A47E'],

colorAxis : {
    dataClassColor : 'category',
    dataClasses : [{
            to : 57.1
        }, {
            from : 57.2,
            to : 60.4
        }, {
            from : 60.5
        }
    ]
},
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/patelriki13/q2yww0vw/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Highcharts 3.0.10, to set colours.